# Having trouble getting rid of the blue highlight

Tags: css, reactjs

I've been working on a section with expandable/collapsible sections. When I click on a section to expand or collapse it, a blue focus area shows up but it is placed on a weird angle. I don't know what is causing it and would like a solution to either get rid of it or place it back at the normal horizontal angle. Does anybody have any suggestions as to how to fix this?

I am using a Macbook and Chrome browser.

The entire grey block that this component appears in is placed at an angle as you can see from the top of the image attached below but in the reverse direction from the highlighted focus area.

[image: Example]

My css:

```
@import '../../theme/variables.css';

.rotatedSection {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.container {
  max-width: 64rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  @media screen and (max-width: 68rem) {
    margin: 0 3rem;
  }
}

.accordianContainer {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  min-width: 500px;
  @media screen and (max-width: $tablet-lg-max-width) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    min-width: 0;
  }
}

.imageContainer {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  img {
    flex: 1;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: $tablet-lg-max-width) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.heading {
  composes: h2 from 'theme/text';
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

My react code:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

import RotatedSection from 'components/RotatedSection';
import AccordionItem from './AccordionItem';

import css from './styles.css';

class AccordionSectionWithImage extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeIndex: null,
    };

    this.onOpen = this.onOpen.bind(this);
    this.onClose = this.onClose.bind(this);
    this.setActive = this.setActive.bind(this);
    this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
  }

  onOpen = (index) => {
    this.setActive(index);
  };

  onClose = (callback = () => null) => {
    this.setActive(null);
    callback();
  };

  setActive = (activeIndex) => this.setState({activeIndex});

  handleClickOutside = () => this.props.collapseOnBlur && this.onClose();

  render () {
    const {
      entry: {
        items,
        heading,
        image,
      },
      showIndex,
      classNames,
      meta = {},
    } = this.props;

    const {routeParams, toggleHamburger} = meta;
    const {activeIndex} = this.state;

    return (
      <RotatedSection color='whisper' className={css.rotatedSection}>
        <div className={css.container}>
          <div className={css.accordianContainer}>
            <h2 className={css.heading}>{heading}</h2>
            {items && items.map((item, index) => (
              <AccordionItem
                key={index}
                showIndex={showIndex}
                entry={item}
                meta={{
                  position: index,
                  isOpen: (index === activeIndex),
                  onOpen: () => this.onOpen(index),
                  onClose: () => this.onClose(),
                  onChildClick: () => this.onClose(toggleHamburger),
                  routeParams,
                }}
                classNames={classNames}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className={css.imageContainer}>
            <img src={image && image.fields && image.fields.file.url} alt='Educational assessment' />
          </div>
        </div>
      </RotatedSection>
    );
  }
}

AccordionSectionWithImage.propTypes = {
  meta: PropTypes.object,
  entry: PropTypes.object,
  collapseOnBlur: PropTypes.bool,
  showIndex: PropTypes.bool,
  classNames: PropTypes.object,
};

export default AccordionSectionWithImage;
```

React component for individual section:

```
function AccordionItem (props) {
  const {
    meta: {
      isOpen,
      onOpen,
      onClose,
    },
    entry: {
      heading,
      text,
    },
  } = props;

  const handleClick = () => (isOpen ? onClose() : onOpen());

  return (
    <div className={css.itemContainer}>
      <div className={css.innerContainer}>
        <h3 className={css.heading} onClick={handleClick}>
          <span className={css.titleText}>{heading}</span>
          <i className={`zmdi zmdi-plus ${css.titleToggle}`} />
        </h3>
        {isOpen && (
          <div className={css.contents}>
            {text}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's likely an inherited styled. You'll have to use the Chrome inspect to see what element it is and why it's styled that way. It could be a mixture of styles where one style is applying the color and another the rotation.

Comment: I'm unable to find the element in Chrome inspector. It appears to be an active style but forcing the active trait on all the elements in that area doesn't reproduce it. Just clicking on it.

Comment: I don't see that style in the CSS you posted. You'll have to explore around using inspector to find it.

Comment: Further investigation has revealed that it only occurs when chrome inspector is in device mode. So probably a style associated with tap select.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else experiencing a similar problem:

Problem only appeared on mobile phones and the device mode of chrome inspector. It was due to the tap-highlight property.

Setting -webkit-tap-highlight-color to rgba(0,0,0,0) hid the problem but it's a non standard css property so the solution may not work for all devices/browsers/users.